# Terminal shows root@homeserver when logging in with user

Tags: ssh, root

I have an Ubuntu Server 12.04 running on a Dell D620 Machine called "homeserver".

Everytime i log into the SSH with the user homeserver (yes same name as machine) the terminal shows root@homeserver.

i looks like i even have admin rights.

The last thing I've done was trying to install Roundcube on the machine.

What is the possible reason for this problem?

edit:

I log in from my windows machine with putty
homeserver@192.168.178.20 <-- IP of the machine

```
root@homeserver:~# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) Gruppen=0(root),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),111(sambashare),113(lpadmin)

root@homeserver:~# who
homeserver pts/0        2012-07-22 13:30 (dennis-ibm-laptop.fritz.box)
```

edit2:

```
root@homeserver:~# getent passwd homeserver
homeserver:x:0:0:homeserver,,,:/home/homeserver:/bin/bash
```

Comment: Show the exact `ssh` command you use, and what does `id` say after logging in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` command says you are root, but the `who` command says you're logged in as user homeserver. It sounds like both users, homeserver and root, has uid 0.

```
getent passwd homeserver
```

Comment: @DennisSchma, my suspision was confirmed. The third colon-separated field is the uid, which says 0 for your homeserver user. Thus homeserver and root is the exact same user. How did you create the user?

Comment: this is the way I installed the server and before it logged in as homeserver... is there a way to change the UID?

Comment: @DennisSchma homeserver is the initial user you created during installation? That's odd, it should've given the initial user uid 1000.

Comment: yes homeserver is the user I created at installation. is there a way to change the UID of a user?

Comment: @DennisSchma, yes, you can edit `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`, and change uid and gid of the homeserver user and group, but you must also change ownership of the homedir and any files that user should own.

Comment: Thanks that solved the issue... what is the standard user group for this user?

Comment: @DennisSchma The initial user you create during install should have uid 1000, and a group by the same name and gid 1000 will also be created and set as that user's primary group.